# Measurability of a function taking values in the extended real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $f:X\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $Y = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $f$ is measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(\{-\infty \})\in M$, $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})\in M$, and $f$ is measurable on $Y$

Proof $\Rightarrow$ Suppose $f:X\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $Y = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, and $f$ is measurable. Since, $f$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}(B)\in M$ for all Borel sets $B\subset \mathbb{R}$. This directly implies that $f^{-1}(\{-\infty \})\in M$, $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})\in M$, and $f$ is measurable on $Y$ since $\mathbb{R}\in B_{\overline{\mathbb{R}}},Y = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ hence $f^{-1}(B)\cap Y\in M$.

$\Leftarrow$ Now, suppose $f^{-1}(\{-\infty \})\in M$, $f^{-1}(\{\infty\})\in M$ and $f$ is measurable on $Y$. For this part I want to define some set that shows $Y = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$. Actually I want to define set $Y$ to be something in which $f^{-1}(Y) = \mathbb{R}$ then the result follows, any suggestions?

I am not sure if this is correct, any suggestions or hints is greatly appreciated.

Source: Real Analysis, Folland problem 2.1.1

Comment: It's nice that you cite the source of problems, but please don't replace the title with this. Titles should give an idea of what the question is about. Nobody knows off the top of their head what Folland's problem 2.1.1 is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to supply a little more detail to support "$f$ is measurable on $Y$".
2. What about the converse?

Comment: for 1. since $f^{-1}(Y) = X$, and $X\in M$. for 2, I havent proved the converse I just wanted to verify that I am on the right track, am I?

Comment: Also, could you provide a hint for the converse?